# can't retrieve src attribute with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

Good day, I have a small rpoblem that I can't retrieve src html attribute out of document.getElementById

```
<div id="1" src="great.png">

var a = document.getElementById(1).src;
document.write(a);
```

gives nothing.

Comment: `var a = document.getElementById("1").src;` Id has to be a string when passing to getElementById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src` is non-understand attribute for `div` tag. you need to use `getAttribute('src')`

```js
var a = document.getElementById("1");
console.log( a.getAttribute('src') );
console.log( a.src ); // undefined
```

```html
<div id="1" src="great.png">
```

Using `img` tag

```js
var a = document.getElementById("1");
console.log( a.getAttribute('src') );
console.log( a.src );
```

```html
<img id="1" src="great.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `src` attribute for `div`. Still you can use `getAttribute` to retrive it.

Also you need to pass `id` as string. Beside note use of `pre` for `document.write`

```
var a = document.getElementById('1').getAttribute('src');
document.write('<pre>'+a+'</pre>');
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/stLdf95u/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
<body>
    <div id="1" src="great.png">
</body>
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById(1).getAttribute("src");
    document.write(a);
</script>
```